# An apostrophe is rendering as â€tm. What PHP function will display it as ' ? something_Decode?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm grabbing some tweets and printing them out on my site and curly apostrophes are being rendered as "â€tm".  This is not good.  What php function should I run the string through to get these weird characters to display as something closer to '?

Comment: `something_Decode` is actually `utf8_decode()`

Comment: Unfortunately that turns the â€tm into �??

Comment: What encoding are you using on your webpage?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Post the code you use to read and display the tweets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to use the following function:

```
function htmlallentities($str){
  $res = '';
  $strlen = strlen($str);
  for($i=0; $i<$strlen; $i++){
    $byte = ord($str[$i]);
    if($byte < 128) // 1-byte char
      $res .= $str[$i];
    elseif($byte < 192); // invalid utf8
    elseif($byte < 224) // 2-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((63&$byte)*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
    elseif($byte < 240) // 3-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
    elseif($byte < 248) // 4-byte char
      $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*262144 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
  }
  return $res;
}
```

call:

```
$str = htmlallentities($str);
```

this will change utf-8-chars into htmlentities, so you can display them in different encodings.

Comment: I added that function to my page, ran the string through an printed out the result, but it didn't change anything in the string.  Is there something more I should do with this code to make it do what it do something?

Comment: Nothing changed? I think you have to call utf8_decode() before: $str = htmlallentities(utf8_decode($str));

Comment: Progress!  That changed the foreign characters into ⿿.  :)  Now what?

Comment: It did not.  After that last step, I checked the source and the weird square things were shown as "&#12287;".  I ran a string replace for them and they're showing ' now.  It's dirty, but it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I was having trouble in Chrome with this.

Adding a

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

to the "head" section fixes it

Comment: This was all I needed to fix it displaying in my circumstances, cheers.

Answer (score 8):

I battled with this for almost a day and then found that this function will work 100% of the time. It works with utf-8 and unicode and converts characters that are beyond the base ascii set into their html entities. It's good for cleaning up MS Word rubbish.

```
function filterText($text) 
{ 

    //UTF-8 filter
    $conv = array(
          "\xC2\xA0" => '&nbsp;',
          "\xC2\xA1" => '&iexcl;',
          "\xC2\xA2" => '&cent;',
          "\xC2\xA3" => '&pound;',
          "\xC2\xA4" => '&curren;',
          "\xC2\xA5" => '&yen;',
          "\xC2\xA6" => '&brvbar;',
          "\xC2\xA7" => '&sect;',
          "\xC2\xA8" => '&uml;',
          "\xC2\xA9" => '&copy;',
          "\xC2\xAA" => '&ordf;',
          "\xC2\xAB" => '&laquo;',
          "\xC2\xAC" => '&not;',
          "\xC2\xAD" => '&shy;',
          "\xC2\xAE" => '&reg;',
          "\xC2\xAF" => '&macr;',
          "\xC2\xB0" => '&deg;',
          "\xC2\xB1" => '&plusmn;',
          "\xC2\xB2" => '&sup2;',
          "\xC2\xB3" => '&sup3;',
          "\xC2\xB4" => '&acute;',
          "\xC2\xB5" => '&micro;',
          "\xC2\xB6" => '&para;',
          "\xC2\xB7" => '&middot;',
          "\xC2\xB8" => '&cedil;',
          "\xC2\xB9" => '&sup1;',
          "\xC2\xBA" => '&ordm;',
          "\xC2\xBB" => '&raquo;',
          "\xC2\xBC" => '&frac14;',
          "\xC2\xBD" => '&frac12;',
          "\xC2\xBE" => '&frac34;',
          "\xC2\xBF" => '&iquest;',
          "\xC3\x80" => '&Agrave;',
          "\xC3\x81" => '&Aacute;',
          "\xC3\x82" => '&Acirc;',
          "\xC3\x83" => '&Atilde;',
          "\xC3\x84" => '&Auml;',
          "\xC3\x85" => '&Aring;',
          "\xC3\x86" => '&AElig;',
          "\xC3\x87" => '&Ccedil;',
          "\xC3\x88" => '&Egrave;',
          "\xC3\x89" => '&Eacute;',
          "\xC3\x8A" => '&Ecirc;',
          "\xC3\x8B" => '&Euml;',
          "\xC3\x8C" => '&Igrave;',
          "\xC3\x8D" => '&Iacute;',
          "\xC3\x8E" => '&Icirc;',
          "\xC3\x8F" => '&Iuml;',
          "\xC3\x90" => '&ETH;',
          "\xC3\x91" => '&Ntilde;',
          "\xC3\x92" => '&Ograve;',
          "\xC3\x93" => '&Oacute;',
          "\xC3\x94" => '&Ocirc;',
          "\xC3\x95" => '&Otilde;',
          "\xC3\x96" => '&Ouml;',
          "\xC3\x97" => '&times;',
          "\xC3\x98" => '&Oslash;',
          "\xC3\x99" => '&Ugrave;',
          "\xC3\x9A" => '&Uacute;',
          "\xC3\x9B" => '&Ucirc;',
          "\xC3\x9C" => '&Uuml;',
          "\xC3\x9D" => '&Yacute;',
          "\xC3\x9E" => '&THORN;',
          "\xC3\x9F" => '&szlig;',
          "\xC3\xA0" => '&agrave;',
          "\xC3\xA1" => '&aacute;',
          "\xC3\xA2" => '&acirc;',
          "\xC3\xA3" => '&atilde;',
          "\xC3\xA4" => '&auml;',
          "\xC3\xA5" => '&aring;',
          "\xC3\xA6" => '&aelig;',
          "\xC3\xA7" => '&ccedil;',
          "\xC3\xA8" => '&egrave;',
          "\xC3\xA9" => '&eacute;',
          "\xC3\xAA" => '&ecirc;',
          "\xC3\xAB" => '&euml;',
          "\xC3\xAC" => '&igrave;',
          "\xC3\xAD" => '&iacute;',
          "\xC3\xAE" => '&icirc;',
          "\xC3\xAF" => '&iuml;',
          "\xC3\xB0" => '&eth;',
          "\xC3\xB1" => '&ntilde;',
          "\xC3\xB2" => '&ograve;',
          "\xC3\xB3" => '&oacute;',
          "\xC3\xB4" => '&ocirc;',
          "\xC3\xB5" => '&otilde;',
          "\xC3\xB6" => '&ouml;',
          "\xC3\xB7" => '&divide;',
          "\xC3\xB8" => '&oslash;',
          "\xC3\xB9" => '&ugrave;',
          "\xC3\xBA" => '&uacute;',
          "\xC3\xBB" => '&ucirc;',
          "\xC3\xBC" => '&uuml;',
          "\xC3\xBD" => '&yacute;',
          "\xC3\xBE" => '&thorn;',
          "\xC3\xBF" => '&yuml;',
          // Latin Extended-A
          "\xC5\x92" => '&OElig;',
          "\xC5\x93" => '&oelig;',
          "\xC5\xA0" => '&Scaron;',
          "\xC5\xA1" => '&scaron;',
          "\xC5\xB8" => '&Yuml;',
          // Spacing Modifier Letters
          "\xCB\x86" => '&circ;',
          "\xCB\x9C" => '&tilde;',
          // General Punctuation
          "\xE2\x80\x82" => '&ensp;',
          "\xE2\x80\x83" => '&emsp;',
          "\xE2\x80\x89" => '&thinsp;',
          "\xE2\x80\x8C" => '&zwnj;',
          "\xE2\x80\x8D" => '&zwj;',
          "\xE2\x80\x8E" => '&lrm;',
          "\xE2\x80\x8F" => '&rlm;',
          "\xE2\x80\x93" => '&ndash;',
          "\xE2\x80\x94" => '&mdash;',
          "\xE2\x80\x98" => '&lsquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\x99" => '&rsquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\x9A" => '&sbquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\x9C" => '&ldquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\x9D" => '&rdquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\x9E" => '&bdquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\xA0" => '&dagger;',
          "\xE2\x80\xA1" => '&Dagger;',
          "\xE2\x80\xB0" => '&permil;',
          "\xE2\x80\xB9" => '&lsaquo;',
          "\xE2\x80\xBA" => '&rsaquo;',
          "\xE2\x82\xAC" => '&euro;',
          // Latin Extended-B
          "\xC6\x92" => '&fnof;',
          // Greek
          "\xCE\x91" => '&Alpha;',
          "\xCE\x92" => '&Beta;',
          "\xCE\x93" => '&Gamma;',
          "\xCE\x94" => '&Delta;',
          "\xCE\x95" => '&Epsilon;',
          "\xCE\x96" => '&Zeta;',
          "\xCE\x97" => '&Eta;',
          "\xCE\x98" => '&Theta;',
          "\xCE\x99" => '&Iota;',
          "\xCE\x9A" => '&Kappa;',
          "\xCE\x9B" => '&Lambda;',
          "\xCE\x9C" => '&Mu;',
          "\xCE\x9D" => '&Nu;',
          "\xCE\x9E" => '&Xi;',
          "\xCE\x9F" => '&Omicron;',
          "\xCE\xA0" => '&Pi;',
          "\xCE\xA1" => '&Rho;',
          "\xCE\xA3" => '&Sigma;',
          "\xCE\xA4" => '&Tau;',
          "\xCE\xA5" => '&Upsilon;',
          "\xCE\xA6" => '&Phi;',
          "\xCE\xA7" => '&Chi;',
          "\xCE\xA8" => '&Psi;',
          "\xCE\xA9" => '&Omega;',
          "\xCE\xB1" => '&alpha;',
          "\xCE\xB2" => '&beta;',
          "\xCE\xB3" => '&gamma;',
          "\xCE\xB4" => '&delta;',
          "\xCE\xB5" => '&epsilon;',
          "\xCE\xB6" => '&zeta;',
          "\xCE\xB7" => '&eta;',
          "\xCE\xB8" => '&theta;',
          "\xCE\xB9" => '&iota;',
          "\xCE\xBA" => '&kappa;',
          "\xCE\xBB" => '&lambda;',
          "\xCE\xBC" => '&mu;',
          "\xCE\xBD" => '&nu;',
          "\xCE\xBE" => '&xi;',
          "\xCE\xBF" => '&omicron;',
          "\xCF\x80" => '&pi;',
          "\xCF\x81" => '&rho;',
          "\xCF\x82" => '&sigmaf;',
          "\xCF\x83" => '&sigma;',
          "\xCF\x84" => '&tau;',
          "\xCF\x85" => '&upsilon;',
          "\xCF\x86" => '&phi;',
          "\xCF\x87" => '&chi;',
          "\xCF\x88" => '&psi;',
          "\xCF\x89" => '&omega;',
          "\xCF\x91" => '&thetasym;',
          "\xCF\x92" => '&upsih;',
          "\xCF\x96" => '&piv;',
          // General Punctuation
          "\xE2\x80\xA2" => '&bull;',
          "\xE2\x80\xA6" => '&hellip;',
          "\xE2\x80\xB2" => '&prime;',
          "\xE2\x80\xB3" => '&Prime;',
          "\xE2\x80\xBE" => '&oline;',
          "\xE2\x81\x84" => '&frasl;',
          // Letterlike Symbols
          "\xE2\x84\x98" => '&weierp;',
          "\xE2\x84\x91" => '&image;',
          "\xE2\x84\x9C" => '&real;',
          "\xE2\x84\xA2" => '&trade;',
          "\xE2\x84\xB5" => '&alefsym;',
          // Arrows
          "\xE2\x86\x90" => '&larr;',
          "\xE2\x86\x91" => '&uarr;',
          "\xE2\x86\x92" => '&rarr;',
          "\xE2\x86\x93" => '&darr;',
          "\xE2\x86\x94" => '&harr;',
          "\xE2\x86\xB5" => '&crarr;',
          "\xE2\x87\x90" => '&lArr;',
          "\xE2\x87\x91" => '&uArr;',
          "\xE2\x87\x92" => '&rArr;',
          "\xE2\x87\x93" => '&dArr;',
          "\xE2\x87\x94" => '&hArr;',
          // Mathematical Operators
          "\xE2\x88\x80" => '&forall;',
          "\xE2\x88\x82" => '&part;',
          "\xE2\x88\x83" => '&exist;',
          "\xE2\x88\x85" => '&empty;',
          "\xE2\x88\x87" => '&nabla;',
          "\xE2\x88\x88" => '&isin;',
          "\xE2\x88\x89" => '&notin;',
          "\xE2\x88\x8B" => '&ni;',
          "\xE2\x88\x8F" => '&prod;',
          "\xE2\x88\x91" => '&sum;',
          "\xE2\x88\x92" => '&minus;',
          "\xE2\x88\x97" => '&lowast;',
          "\xE2\x88\x9A" => '&radic;',
          "\xE2\x88\x9D" => '&prop;',
          "\xE2\x88\x9E" => '&infin;',
          "\xE2\x88\xA0" => '&ang;',
          "\xE2\x88\xA7" => '&and;',
          "\xE2\x88\xA8" => '&or;',
          "\xE2\x88\xA9" => '&cap;',
          "\xE2\x88\xAA" => '&cup;',
          "\xE2\x88\xAB" => '&int;',
          "\xE2\x88\xB4" => '&there4;',
          "\xE2\x88\xBC" => '&sim;',
          "\xE2\x89\x85" => '&cong;',
          "\xE2\x89\x88" => '&asymp;',
          "\xE2\x89\xA0" => '&ne;',
          "\xE2\x89\xA1" => '&equiv;',
          "\xE2\x89\xA4" => '&le;',
          "\xE2\x89\xA5" => '&ge;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x82" => '&sub;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x83" => '&sup;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x84" => '&nsub;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x86" => '&sube;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x87" => '&supe;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x95" => '&oplus;',
          "\xE2\x8A\x97" => '&otimes;',
          "\xE2\x8A\xA5" => '&perp;',
          "\xE2\x8B\x85" => '&sdot;',
          // Miscellaneous Technical
          "\xE2\x8C\x88" => '&lceil;',
          "\xE2\x8C\x89" => '&rceil;',
          "\xE2\x8C\x8A" => '&lfloor;',
          "\xE2\x8C\x8B" => '&rfloor;',
          "\xE2\x8C\xA9" => '&lang;',
          "\xE2\x8C\xAA" => '&rang;',
          // Geometric Shapes
          "\xE2\x97\x8A" => '&loz;',
          // Miscellaneous Symbols
          "\xE2\x99\xA0" => '&spades;',
          "\xE2\x99\xA3" => '&clubs;',
          "\xE2\x99\xA5" => '&hearts;',
          "\xE2\x99\xA6" => '&diams;'
   );

    $string = strtr($text, $conv); 

    //now translate any unicode stuff... 
    $conv = array(
        chr(128) => "&euro;",
        chr(130) => "&sbquo;",
        chr(131) => "&fnof;",
        chr(132) => "&bdquo;",
        chr(133) => "&hellip;",
        chr(134) => "&dagger;",
        chr(135) => "&Dagger;",
        chr(136) => "&circ;",
        chr(137) => "&permil;",
        chr(138) => "&Scaron;",
        chr(139) => "&lsaquo;",
        chr(140) => "&OElig;",
        chr(145) => "&lsquo;",
        chr(146) => "&rsquo;",
        chr(147) => "&ldquo;",
        chr(148) => "&rdquo;",
        chr(149) => "&bull;",
        chr(150) => "&ndash;",
        chr(151) => "&mdash;",
        chr(152) => "&tilde;",
        chr(153) => "&trade;",
        chr(154) => "&scaron;",
        chr(155) => "&rsaquo;",
        chr(156) => "&oelig;",
        chr(159) => "&yuml;",
        chr(160) => "&nbsp;",
        chr(161) => "&iexcl;",
        chr(162) => "&cent;",
        chr(163) => "&pound;",
        chr(164) => "&curren;",
        chr(165) => "&yen;",
        chr(166) => "&brvbar;",
        chr(167) => "&sect;",
        chr(168) => "&uml;",
        chr(169) => "&copy;",
        chr(170) => "&ordf;",
        chr(171) => "&laquo;",
        chr(172) => "&not;",
        chr(173) => "&shy;",
        chr(174) => "&reg;",
        chr(175) => "&macr;",
        chr(176) => "&deg;",
        chr(177) => "&plusmn;",
        chr(178) => "&sup2;",
        chr(179) => "&sup3;",
        chr(180) => "&acute;",
        chr(181) => "&micro;",
        chr(182) => "&para;",
        chr(183) => "&middot;",
        chr(184) => "&cedil;",
        chr(185) => "&sup1;",
        chr(186) => "&ordm;",
        chr(187) => "&raquo;",
        chr(188) => "&frac14;",
        chr(189) => "&frac12;",
        chr(190) => "&frac34;",
        chr(191) => "&iquest;",
        chr(192) => "&Agrave;",
        chr(193) => "&Aacute;",
        chr(194) => "&Acirc;",
        chr(195) => "&Atilde;",
        chr(196) => "&Auml;",
        chr(197) => "&Aring;",
        chr(198) => "&AElig;",
        chr(199) => "&Ccedil;",
        chr(200) => "&Egrave;",
        chr(201) => "&Eacute;",
        chr(202) => "&Ecirc;",
        chr(203) => "&Euml;",
        chr(204) => "&Igrave;",
        chr(205) => "&Iacute;",
        chr(206) => "&Icirc;",
        chr(207) => "&Iuml;",
        chr(208) => "&ETH;",
        chr(209) => "&Ntilde;",
        chr(210) => "&Ograve;",
        chr(211) => "&Oacute;",
        chr(212) => "&Ocirc;",
        chr(213) => "&Otilde;",
        chr(214) => "&Ouml;",
        chr(215) => "&times;",
        chr(216) => "&Oslash;",
        chr(217) => "&Ugrave;",
        chr(218) => "&Uacute;",
        chr(219) => "&Ucirc;",
        chr(220) => "&Uuml;",
        chr(221) => "&Yacute;",
        chr(222) => "&THORN;",
        chr(223) => "&szlig;",
        chr(224) => "&agrave;",
        chr(225) => "&aacute;",
        chr(226) => "&acirc;",
        chr(227) => "&atilde;",
        chr(228) => "&auml;",
        chr(229) => "&aring;",
        chr(230) => "&aelig;",
        chr(231) => "&ccedil;",
        chr(232) => "&egrave;",
        chr(233) => "&eacute;",
        chr(234) => "&ecirc;",
        chr(235) => "&euml;",
        chr(236) => "&igrave;",
        chr(237) => "&iacute;",
        chr(238) => "&icirc;",
        chr(239) => "&iuml;",
        chr(240) => "&eth;",
        chr(241) => "&ntilde;",
        chr(242) => "&ograve;",
        chr(243) => "&oacute;",
        chr(244) => "&ocirc;",
        chr(245) => "&otilde;",
        chr(246) => "&ouml;",
        chr(247) => "&divide;",
        chr(248) => "&oslash;",
        chr(249) => "&ugrave;",
        chr(250) => "&uacute;",
        chr(251) => "&ucirc;",
        chr(252) => "&uuml;",
        chr(253) => "&yacute;",
        chr(254) => "&thorn;",
        chr(255) => "&yuml;");


return strtr($string, $conv);   


}
```

Answer (score 4):

`str_replace('â€tm', "'", $dirty_string)` might give you a quick and dirty fix. But it seems to me like a character encoding problem. You may read the tweets using an encoding and displaying them in another encoding.

**You'd have to check your code and make sure you use the same encoding all over the place if you wanna do this the "clean way"**.

Comment: Is there a PHP function I can run this string through on the fly to clean it up?  I.E. UTF8_encode($string); ?

Comment: I'm trying the str_replace approach, but for some reason the function isn't "seeing" â€™ when it goes through it looking for the string to replace.  So nothing happens when I print out that function.  The text stays unchanged.

Comment: are you sure you're using utf8 encoding? how did you get the `â€tm` char? did you use view-source or simply copy/paste from the page? you should use view source. The character might appear differently in the page source

Comment: Good point!  View source showed it as &#12287;.  String replace worked for replace those.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To convert to HTML entities:

```
<?php
  echo mb_convert_encoding(
    file_get_contents('http://www.tvrage.com/quickinfo.php?show=Surviver&ep=20x02&exact=0'),
    "HTML-ENTITIES",
    "UTF-8"
  );
```

See docs for mb_convert_encoding for more encoding options.