# Bookmarklet - charset - special characters

Tags: php, javascript, sql, bookmarklet, collation

I'm working on a bookmarklet and sending a few informations about the current site to a php script.

I have some trouble with the site title.
For example, if the site title is

```
urban archaeology: sleeping beauty’s paris apartment
```

It looks like this in the sql database

```
urban archaeology: sleeping beautyâ€™s paris apartment
```

Is it because of the collation of the field? It's latin1_swedish_ci at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your html header specifies utf8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Normaly does the trick (obviously if the content IS utf8).

Comment: Also if your data has allready been stored in your database screwey then you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583369/an-apostrophe-is-rendering-as-atm-what-php-function-will-display-it-as-som

Comment: Like i said in my comment if your data has allready been stored badly into your database its trashed and you will have to use a function like the one in the link above to clean it up. Or go through your database and do a manual clean up

Comment: Okay I fixed it, utf8_decode() did the trick! // EDIT: iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data) work's even better!

Answer (score 0):

Change the collation to UTF-8.

Comment: Done. But it looks still the same