# Converting smart quotes and other entities to exact form

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, html-entities, iso

I have been working with converting strings to PDFs. A typical problem that arises is the occasional 'smart quote' or other utf-8 character which becomes one or another ISO character such as â€“, â€™, â€œ , â€, etc. The function defined below solves said problem by encoding them to html entities, however, of course a PDF is not html. When inputting a string with `â€™` in place for an apostrophe `’`, the function converts it to `&#8217;`. That's great if we were dealing with HTML, but as a PDF, it treats it as a string and therefore it's exact form is never converted. Therefore, how does one covert the htmlentity to the characters *exact* form?

```
function htmlallentities($str){
    $res = '';
    $strlen = strlen($str);
    for($i=0; $i<$strlen; $i++){
        $byte = ord($str[$i]);
        if($byte < 128) { // 1-byte char
            $res .= $str[$i];
        } elseif($byte < 192) { // invalid utf8
        } elseif($byte < 224) { // 2-byte char
            $res .= '&#'.((63&$byte)*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
        } elseif($byte < 240) { // 3-byte char
            $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
        } elseif($byte < 248) { // 4-byte char
            $res .= '&#'.((15&$byte)*262144 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*4096 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))*64 + (63&ord($str[++$i]))).';';
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

(With thanks to @Floern, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4583465/810821)

If I have used incorrect terminology, my apologies.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the smart apostrophe (’) becomes â€™, then the problem is that UTF-8 encoded data is being interpreted as a byte sequence in windows-1252 encoding. Instead of trying to fix this after the data has been messed up, you should find and fix the part of code that causes the wrong interpretation.